# Formatting Date with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using the [Simple Form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) in my Rails app.  In my sign-up form, I'm have a field for birth date.  However, the fields are showing in this order: Year/Month/Day.

What's the best way to get the field order Month - Day - Year?

My form looks like this:

```
 <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :created_at %>          
   <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>      
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
<%= f.input :birthday, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it will work with simple_form, but I suspect it will... Add the following to `config/locals/en.yml` (or similar):

```
en:
  date:
    order:
      - :month
      - :day
      - :year
```

Comment: That's perfect if you don't know if the field will be a date or not, and therefore you cannot pass the `:order` option explicitly